# return user permissions to root, sudo broken

Tags: permissions, root, chown

i've been having troubles importing CA certificates using the terminal, so I pulled an idiot move and did `sudo chown user /usr/` in order to copypaste the CA cert into the desired folder, now sudo doesn't work in terminal, and I can't figure out how to reset user permissions to root. Am I SOL/FUBAR/SNAFU?

Comment: Reinstall the system.

Comment: Basically, the same response to when you 'accidentally' `chown -R` system directories.